# Вставить компонент уже в прогруженную страницу через jquery Angular

Tags: jquery, angular

Всем привет. Такая задача, на сервер отправляется формы изменения пароля, приходят 2-а вида сообщений, в колбэк функции они обрабатываются.

```
public callback(data)
{
    if (data.success) {
        $("#changePasswordBtn").after(`<alert-suc [message]="'${data.message}'"></alert-suc>`);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#changePasswordBtn").after(`<alert-fail [message]="'${data.message}'"></alert-fail>`);
    }
    
    console.log(data);
}
```

Здесь я пытаюсь вставить после кнопки селектр компонента `<alert-fail>` либо `<alert-suc>` и передать в него параметр с сообщением. Однако после вставки элемент не рендерится.

Вот сам компонент который вставляется ts:

```
    import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'alert-fail',
    templateUrl: 'failAlert.component.html'
})

export class FailAlertComponent
{
    @Input() message: string = "";
}
```

html:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 py-1" role="alert">
    {{message}}
  </div>
```

Вот скриншот результата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Стрелка сверху - как оно вставилось
2. Стрелка снизу - как оно должно быть, этот элемент я поместил в html
   код заранее.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, зачем использовать одновременно Angular и JQuery. Если вам нужно вставлять в html-шаблон страницы, то почему не использовать `*ngIf`, `[hidden]`, или что-нибудь подобное?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Потому-что уведомлений может быть несколько, и для каждого делать свой alert затратно. Будет портить код, к тому же будет ухудшена ремонтопригодность кода, а так же будет сложнее внедрять обновления.

Comment: Если у вас несколько уведомлений, то проще использовать массив для хранения уведомлений и выводить их через `*ngFor`. Использовать jQuery и Angular вместе довольно сложно, ибо они могут негативно влиять на работу друг друга (был опыт такого проекта).

Comment: Что мешает директиву создать для подобного?... и компактно, и универсально, и костылять не надо

Comment: @InDevX Я новичок в angular, не совсем понимаю как директива может здесь компактно примениться, и одновременно быть универсальной в других модулях. Можешь расписать пример?